# Py2exe with tweepy

Tags: python, py2exe, tweepy

Here is my setup.py file :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['main.py'])
```

In my `main.py` I use **tweepy**. I get that error when I execute my `main.exe` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

Does someone understand that error ?

(tweepy is already install and my python file works very well)

Thanks !!!

Comment: Did [py2exe's page on this error](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/DealingWithImportError) not help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an import statement, this should suffice:

```
import tweepy
```